# Probability of a document in Multinomial Naive Bayes Model

Tags: nlp

To my shame, I can't fully understand the meaning one of the fragment in the formula of the probability of a document in Multinomial Naive Bayes Model.
It is about paper [A Comparison of Event Models for Naive Bayes Text Classication](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.65.9324), formula #5:

[image]

The problematic fragment is `P(|d_i|)` - I can't fully understand, what does this probability mean? Does it simply probability of the i-th document? If so, why it contains `|...|` operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|d_i|` is the number of words in the ith document. The `P(|d_i|)` term is the probability of generating a document with exactly `|d_i|` words.

Comment: You are really confused.  Naive bayes has nothing do with the LDA formula you edited into my response.

Comment: Really? Ok, and how you suggest to calculate the probability of generating a document with N words?

Comment: Well, for the document categoriziation task described in the paper, document length doesn't matter to the distribution over classes given a document.  That is, longer documents don't bias your choice towards or away from any particular category.  If you wanted to model document length for some other reasons (or because you think it will help with your task), this paper suggests using a pareto distribution.  http://allendowney.com/research/filesize/Downey01Structural.ps.gz

Comment: It's worth noting several things. The formula treats length and class independently and thus the term is constant. You could model them as dependent (have a term p(d_i|c_j)) which might be useful for certain tasks. Not sure what the benefit of a Pareto distribution would be, however, over say a Poisson (if you wanted something discrete) or a log-normal, where those are both much easier to work with. Finally, note that since the multinomial produces extreme probabilities (small numbers to big powers = very small numbers), modelling the length may have no effect on the decisions.